# Make an input that only allow numbers, one dot and two decimal places

Tags: javascript

There's any way to validate in javascript multiple inputs in order to just allow numbers, one dot and two optional decimal places in each of them?

**EDIT:**
It should allow the next ones:

- 12.65
- 12.6
- 12.
- 12
- 1

I managed to do this:

```
<input type="number" onkeypress="return isDecimalKey(event,this)"/>
<input type="text" onkeypress="return isDecimalKey(event,this)"/>
<input type="number" onkeypress="return isDecimalKey(event,this)"/>
<input type="text" onkeypress="return isDecimalKey(event,this)"/>
```

```
function isDecimalKey(evt, elem) {

    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
    if (charCode > 31 && (charCode != 46 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)))
        return false;
    else {
        var dot = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < elem.value.toString().length; i++) {
            if (elem.value.toString()[i] == 46)
                dot++;
        }
        if (charCode == 46 && dot == 1)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

But it doesn't work well, and I'm still able to insert multiple dots and more than 2 decimals, but only accepts numbers and dots.

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to use a regex? /^[0-9]+\.[0-9]{2}$/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with this

**HTML**

```
<input autofocus pattern="^\d+\.{0,1}\d{0,2}$" required oninput="isDecimalKey(event,this)">
```

**JS**

```
const isDecimalKey = (event,element)=>{
       event.target.setCustomValidity('');
      const patt = /^\d+\.{0,1}\d{0,2}$/;
      let value = event.target.value;
      if(!patt.test(value)){
        event.target.reportValidity();
        element.setAttribute("maxlength",value.length);
      }
      else
      {
        element.removeAttribute("maxlength")
      }
     if(value.length === 0){
        element.removeAttribute("maxlength");
     }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
input type="number" 
step="0.01"
onkeypress={() => { isDecimalKey(event,this) }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following regex to validate your inptut value:

```
[0-9]*\.?[0-9]{2}.test('21.33') //true

[0-9]*\.?[0-9]{2}.test('3333.111') //false
```

Comment: how to apply this?

Comment: <input autofocus pattern="[0-9]*\.?[0-9]{2}" required>